# Нужно ли наращение в паре годов?

Tags: наращение

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли в этой фразе использовать наращение: "с марта 1923[-го] по май 1924 года"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наращение не требуется.

> [Вопрос № 292716](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=292716)
>   Скажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли наращение после 2009 в такой фразе: "С 2009-го по 2011 год он выпускал мужской журнал"?
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Наращение не требуется.